# Possible to lock focal length on zoom lens? (SELP1650)

Tags: lens, focal-length, zoom, creative-process

(This could turn out to be a bone, practical, product-specific query, but this is the internet so the worst that could happen is a 0 rather than a 1.)

Anyhoo: is it possible to lock a zoomable lens to a certain focal length? Is this a typical feature for a lens?

I want to keep my SELP1650 at X mm to help with some creative experiments, but the thing shifts whenever I move my hand against the lens ring. Does SELP1650 (or the body, Sony A6000) specifically have this option?

Or... is there a reasonably non-goofy DIY trick I could pull off, without bricking the thing? (anticipating a sarky 'duct tape' suggestion)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A zoom lock included in the design of a lens was more common back 30-40 years ago than it is today.

And although you might consider suggesting duct tape snarky, you're not too far off from what many experienced photographers use today when they wish to keep a zoom lens at a specific setting for a series of photos: gaffer's tape. It holds well enough but doesn't leave any residue once removed.

[image]

There are several other methods involving wide rubber bands. There's even a company that makes them and specifically markets for this use: [lens bands](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0050KHY5E). Most such bands aren't much different from the wrist bands that have become popular for showing support for various causes. Depending on the size of your lens, one of the wrist bands might fit the bill. I have a rubber wristband on my very well used EF 24-105mm f/4 L IS to prevent zoom creep.

[image]

You can also find a plethora of DIY methods by searching the internet for "fix zoom creep". Some of these methods are lens specific. Including the lens name in your search will help find those specific to your model lens.

Comment: After reading the Amazon reviews, I do like the charity wristband idea... Well shucks, thanks very much for the well-resourced answer :)